# ffmpeg relocation error

Tags: apt, video, compiling, ffmpeg, media-library

I've tried to install FFmpeg from the default repository on 18.04.

```
ffmpeg: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.2:   
symbol av_calloc version LIBAVUTIL_55 not defined in file 
libavutil.so.55 with link time reference
```

I believe I may have broken the shared libraries in the past when I tried to compile ffmpeg from source and then gave up.

Seeing this file in question `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.2` was provided by the package `libswresample2`

```
$ dpkg-query -L libswresample2
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.2.9.100
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libswresample2
/usr/share/doc/libswresample2/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libswresample2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.2
/usr/share/doc/libswresample2/changelog.Debian.gz
```

I tried to reinstall ffmpeg, libswresample-dev, libswresample2, libavutil55, and libavutil-dev and I'm still receiving the same error. I'm trying to avoid compiling ffmpeg from source again if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can always download [static builds](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and use them. This will solve your problem. However, I would recommend you to fix this dependency issue so you can use the latest ffmpeg version after `apt-get update`.